# svg stack doesn't fill all available width and height of img

Tags: image, svg, figma

I'm exporting svgs from figma and unite in [svg stack](https://simurai.com/blog/2012/04/02/svg-stacks) to adress later using icons.svg#ID.
Html code is: `<img src="icons.svg#logo" class="svg-logo-dims"/>`
Class "svg-logo-dims" sets width and height, for example: `width: 20px; height: 20px` for img. Why my svg doesn't cover 20x20? It's centered in img element with a lot of free space. I have to object-fit: cover to make it look like in figma layout.
On the other hand if i insert raw svg in my html, specifying  same width and height it would be really 20x20 without free space.

[image: svg fill img problem]

svg markup (deleted other svgs):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg viewBox="0 0 354 519" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><style>:root>svg{display:none}:root>svg:target{display:block}</style><svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M18.01 5.694a9.092 9.092 0 01-3.718 12.316 9.053 9.053 0 01-5.352 1.02A9.097 9.097 0 015.694 1.976a9.07 9.07 0 018.06-.266 9.055 9.055 0 014.256 3.984z" stroke="url(#hpaint0_linear_0_497)"/><defs><linearGradient id="hpaint0_linear_0_497" x1=".756" y1="8.723" x2="20.965" y2="9.992" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset=".288" stop-color="#555248"/><stop offset=".78" stop-color="#1B1A17" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient></defs></svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i found a solution. [Gulp-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprite) possible has an error. It adds viewBox of first underlying svg and sets it to whole svg tag:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg viewBox="0 0 354 519" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><style>:root>svg{display:none}:root>svg:target{display:block}</style><svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 354 519" id="ads-bg-ico"...</svg></svg>`
After deleting duplicating viewBox from parent svg element, all underlying svgs inside parent svg become to work properly and fill img element.

UPD: with release of svg-sprite 2.0.0 `rootviewbox: false` option added

Comment: I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgstore without pb for years, you may look at it

Comment: @jetzeny, please mark this as your answer